# Finding functions with a given property

Tags: functions, inequality

Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (if they exist) with the property $$f(c)-b^2 \leq f(a+b)-f(a)+f(c) \leq b^2+f(c).$$ I tried setting $a+b=x$ and solving. I get the function needs to have degree 2 if it does exist, but I do not know how to continue the idea...

Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Setting $f(x)=\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \omega$ seems like a lot will simplify

Comment: What is the purpose of $f(c)$ in that inequality chain? One can simply subtract it from each expression and nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given function is equivalent to
$$\begin{align*}&-b^2 \leq f(a+b)-f(a) \leq b^2
\\\\\implies&\bigg|\frac{f(a+b)-f(a)}b\bigg|\leq |b|
\\\\\implies&\lim_{b\to0}\bigg|\frac{f(a+b)-f(a)}b\bigg|\leq \lim_{b\to0}|b|
\\\\\implies& |f'(a)|\leq 0 ~~\forall a\in\mathbb{R}
\\\\\implies &f(x)=c\text{ where c is a constant}\end{align*}$$

Comment: The second line is not correct if $b$ is negative because the inequalities reverse the direction in that case. Better work with absolute values: $|f(a+b)-f(a)| \le |b|^2$ implies  $ \left|\frac{f(a+b)-f(a)}b\right| \leq |b|$.

Comment: @MartinR I have edited my answer